Spring Boot vulnerabilities - JFrog is throwing different vulnerabilities which are not related to my Project

Please check above image once,
Spring boot version 3.3.0 and Java 17
we are not using pip and setup tools in my project side and python also we are not using, but it's throwing pip and setup tools.
and for reference i'm adding pom.xml also

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <modelmapper.version>3.1.1</modelmapper.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.16.0</commons-io.version>
        <springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version>2.5.0</springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version>
        <protobuf.version>3.23.4</protobuf.version>
        <protoc-gen-grpc-java.version>1.57.0</protoc-gen-grpc-java.version>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        <skipUnitTests>${skipTests}</skipUnitTests>
        <skipIntegrationTests>${skipTests}</skipIntegrationTests>
        <skip.surefire.tests>${skipTests}</skip.surefire.tests>
        <allure.version>2.26.0</allure.version>
        <allure-maven-reporting.version>2.10.0</allure-maven-reporting.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.22</aspectj.version>
        <skipSurefireReport>true</skipSurefireReport>
        <dir>${project.build.directory}</dir>
        <quarkus.version>3.12.0</quarkus.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <!-- AspectJ runtime version, in sync with compiler -->
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${allure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- The base Quarkus BOM -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.1.18282</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>${modelmapper.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>lib-common-observability</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-common-observability</artifactId>
            <version>main-2024-01-16.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>lib-common-validations</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-common-validations</artifactId>
            <version>main-2023-11-09.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-jre8-standalone</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tnet</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-hr-sec-authlibrary</artifactId>
            <version>main-2024-02-14.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
            <version>${protobuf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.26</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.110.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http2</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.110.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.111.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope> <!-- not bundle for production as scope is test
            only -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <!-- AspectJ runtime version, in sync with compiler -->
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>2.26.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.resilience4j/resilience4j-spring-boot3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot3</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.11</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime
                    agent which
                     is passed as VM argument when Maven the Failsafe plugin is executed. -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the
                            execution data. -->
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the
                            settings for JaCoCo
                             runtime agent. -->
                            <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for integration
                    tests after
                     integration tests have been run.  -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the
                            execution data. -->
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage
                            report. -->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <reportDirectory>target/allure-report</reportDirectory>
                            <groups>${test.categories}</groups>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*Test.class</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <skipTests>${skipIntegrationTests}</skipTests>
                        </configuration>


                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <allure.results.directory>target/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <groups>${test.categories}</groups>
                    <!-- <skipTests>${skip.surefire.tests}</skipTests> working -->
                    <skipTests>${skipUnitTests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.11.0-M1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>
                        com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protobuf.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>
                        io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${protoc-gen-grpc-java.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                    <protoSourceRoot>${basedir}/interface/v1</protoSourceRoot>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                            <goal>compile-python</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputName>api-wf-hw-bss-prospect</outputName>
                </configuration>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputName>api-wf-hw-bss-prospect</outputName>
                        </configuration>
                        <reports>
                            <report>failsafe-report-only</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${allure-maven-reporting.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>${allure.version}</reportVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>

i don't have any clue how to fix this, please help me on this.
if you need any additional info, please ask in comment section.

Where are these vulnerabilities thrown? Is it a build? IDE plugin? CLI results?

it's from build. we are not getting any vulnerability issues from IDE.

What is the impact path of the vulnerabilities? Simply direct deps to the build?

Yes, we are directly doing, there are no internal steps. and impact path of vulnerabilities means, you are pointing to XRay from JFrog.

Impact Path means where Xray finds the vulnerabilities.
You can see impact path in the UI by clicking on the vulnerability and go to impact paths tab
